# Embed a non-OpenGL rendering surface inside a GTK window

Tags: gtk, x11, gtk3, vulkan, wgpu-rs

I'm making a Rust desktop app that acts as a kind of 3D model viewer. I would need to render both a 3D scene and GTK widgets to control some rendering parameters. I want it to integrate well with the user's desktop and theme, and I'm mainly targeting Ubuntu, hence the choice of GTK. I may eventually port it to other widget libraries and even OSes.

The 3D scene would be rendered with [`wgpu`](https://lib.rs/wgpu/), which is a cross-platform polyfill for the WebGPU API. I believe that `wgpu` currently renders using Vulkan on Linux, but this is abstracted away: [the entry point to choose a rendering surface](https://docs.rs/wgpu/latest/wgpu/struct.Instance.html#method.create_surface) accepts anything that implements `raw_window_handle::HasRawDisplayHandle`, which includes an `XlibDisplayHandle`, an `XcbDisplayHandle`, a `WaylandDisplayHandle` or a `GbmDisplayHandle` to quote a few Linux-related technologies.

Now, from what I understand, GTK is much higher-level than any of these, and it won't be as easy as just having some kind of "surface" widget that can give me one of these handles. So I have two ideas:

- Render to an offscreen buffer, then give the image to Gtk. This creates a GPU/CPU round-trip that may not be desirable but could be acceptable for a 3D model viewer
- Find a way to create and attach an relative-positioned border-less window to another window, to act as the rendering surface. <strike>This means I'll have to implement this for every single display server out there. But I could publish that as a library to help others and receive contributions in return.</strike> Actually, GdkWindow seems to solve this problem for me. That's what GtkGLArea uses internally.

What could I do?

**Note:** I'm doing this in Rust, but any C solution will help me. It's not really hard to translate the code and/or perform C calls from Rust. Most Rust libraries that wrap over C libraries provide escape hatches to work with the C pointers directly.

Comment: I understand that the question is about how to do this in X11, using GTK3? GTK4 and Wayland answer will probably differ a lot, hence my question